# How to convert original yolo weights to TensorRT model?

Tags: yolo, darknet, tensorrt

I have developed an improved version of the yolov4-tiny model.
I would like to convert this developed model to a TensorRT model, but after referring to the attached URL, I found that I can only convert the original v4-tiny model.

My question is, how are other people converting their original models to TensorRT?

Thank you in advance.
[URL](https://github.com/hunglc007/tensorflow-yolov4-tflite.git)

Answer (score 1):

I understood that you have a custom model that you have trained yourself and you want to convert that to TensorRT.

There are many ways to convert the model to TensorRT. The process depends on which format your model is in but here's one that works for all formats:

1. Convert your model to [ONNX](https://onnx.ai/) format
2. Convert the model from ONNX to TensorRT using [trtexec](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/tensorrt/developer-guide/index.html#trtexec)

### Detailed steps

I assume your model is in Pytorch format. At least the `train.py` in the repository you linked saves models to that format. You can convert it to ONNX using [tf2onnx](https://github.com/onnx/tensorflow-onnx).

Note that `tf2onnx` recommends the use of Python 3.7. You can install it [here](https://www.python.org/downloads/) and create a virtual environment using [conda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/) or [venv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) if you are using another version of Python.

Then, install `tf2onnx`:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/onnx/tensorflow-onnx
```

Convert your model from saved-model to ONNX

```
python3 -m tf2onnx.convert --saved-model ./model --output model.onnx
```

If you are using some other tf format for your model please see the readme of tf2onnx for help.

Then install TensorRT and its dependencies using [this guide](https://developer.nvidia.com/tensorrt) if you haven't already installed it. Alternatively you can use [Nvidia Containers (NGC)](https://catalog.ngc.nvidia.com/orgs/nvidia/containers/tensorrt).

After you have installed TensorRT you can do this command to convert your model using `fp16` precision.

```
/usr/src/tensorrt/bin/trtexec --onnx=model.onnx --saveEngine=model.engine --fp16 --workspace=3000 --buildOnly
```

You can check all CLI arguments by running

```
/usr/src/tensorrt/bin/trtexec --help
```

Answer (score 1):

For YOLO v3-v5 You can use project with manual parsing cfg and weight files, manual building and saving engine file for TensorRT. For example [enazoe/yolo-tensorrt](https://github.com/enazoe/yolo-tensorrt/). I'm using this come in [Multitarget-tracker](https://github.com/Smorodov/Multitarget-tracker) as fast objects detector on Windows/Linux x86/Nvidia Jetson.

In this case you doesn't need install *trtexec* and another software from NVidia.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.
Thank you for the instruction.
I will try it once.

Comment: How much FPS you are getting with yolo models on Jetson?

Comment: Depends from model and jetson. I can get a 25 fps on Nano with tiny-yolo and on Xavier NX with YOLO 608x608